# ofstream crashes on first output in extremely simple program (GCC/Code::Blocks)

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, codeblocks, ofstream

I've got a cross-platform logging app that I was developing on Windows with MSVC on the weekend, and then on my linux box using GCC/Code::Blocks this morning it crashes as soon as it opens an output file using ofstream.

The specific code looked like this, and was literally the first 8 lines run in the program

```
stringstream strFile;
strFile<<filename;
strFile<<".result.out";

out.open(strFile.str().c_str());
out<<"Count"<<"\t";
out<<"TM"<<"\t";
out<<"Type"<<"\t";
out<<"Seconds"<<"\t";
```

After figuring out the problem, I later produced a minimal app that had the same symptoms

```
#pragma pack(1) // remove this and it will run without incident
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream out;
    out.open("test.txt");
    for(int x = 0;x < 10000; x++)
    {
      out<<"This is a test"<<endl; // crashes on first output
    }
    out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `#pragma pack(1)` changes the ABI of all subsequently included header files, making the standard C++ library (`.so` or `.a`) incompatible with your application.

The solution is to remove that `#pragma pack(1)`. Apply packing to your structures individually.

Comment: Yep, I discovered that.  However, not a single answer on SO that I could find had that solution, so I figure I'd add that to the corpus of answers.

Comment: @ArtHare Added the solution for you.

Comment: @ArtHare there is as none as it is a simple typographical error. You probably won't find an answer for `cut` (instead of `cout`) error either.

Comment: @SergeyA You are right. I normally use `alignas` to increase alignment.

Comment: Anyway, accepted this answer, since removing #pragma pack(1) and applying individually is the correct answer.  I'll just remove my answer, I guess since it's now in the question...

Answer (score 0):

I strongly encourage everyone to stop using those `pragma pack` attributes specifically for this reason (as they can escape, and I have seen this happening in production as well).

Instead, individually apply pack attributes to structures as needed, using your compiler's syntax (i.e. `attribute packed`).